# php __get question

Tags: php, get

if you declare in class function `getName()`
then if i call `obj->name` i guess `getName()` must called, but i get `Undefined property name`
why?

Comment: Please include a minimal version of your sourcecode.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work like that, it's more like this:

```
class Foo {
    protected $name;

    public function getName() { 
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        switch($key) {
            case 'name':
                return $this->getName();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is correct the getName() function is completely redundant in this scenario.

Comment: @Dai - only because this is a simplified example.  Perhaps the actual getName() does a lot more work (query the database?), and it would be nice to segregate that functionality into its own method rather than clutter up __get().

Comment: Well that's why I qualified my comment with "in this scenario".

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct.

You are probably referring to the magic [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) method, which would work like this:

```
public function __get($name) {
    switch($name) {
        case "name":
            return "whatever";
    }
}
```

This would return `whatever` if you did `$obj->name`.

To return `whatever` from `$obj->getName()`, you would need to override [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) like this:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    if (strpos($name, 'get') !== 0) {
        return;
    }

    $name = substr($name, 3);
    switch($name) {
        case 'Name': // case sensitive!
            return 'whatever';
    }
}
```

[See it in action here](http://ideone.com/lNev9).

**Note:** Normally you would have the names of the properties you can return in an array instead of writing a switch statement with hardcoded values (for much greater flexibility).

Answer (score 0):

The __get method works like this

```
class Test {
    private $var1;
    private $var2;

    function __construct($1, $2) {
        $this->var1 = $1;
        $this->var2 = $2;
    }

    function __get($var) {
        return $this->$var;
    }
}
```

So if you create an instance of this class...

```
$tst = new Test("hello", "world");
print $tst->var1;
```

The result will be

```
hello
```